# How to handle progress bar and other UI update in layout if I restart the activity when downloading?

Tags: android, download

Like in google play store when we download any app, the progress bar in the activity layout is showing the download progress even after we restart the activity and also when we closed and reopen the app.

So, How to handle progress bar and other UI update like play store?

Comment: This is an offtopic question you have to do some research and try to implement it and ask a question if you have any issue during the implementation. You can start with [Android Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Answer (score 1):

You can use notification. There are different types of notification is available.
Notifications can include an animated progress indicator that shows users the status of an ongoing operation.

Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Comment: I want to show the progress bar in the activity layout

Comment: use AsyncTask which give you a call back on task complete. You can also monitor the progress update 
Here is the link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: How to monitor the progress in AsyncTask if I closed and reopen activity?